# Performance "memcpy" incorrect

Tags: riscv

We have an application copying 80MB bulk data from one memory location to other using existing memcpy and unmodified RISCV compiler. We could see the cycle count is ~900 which seems incorrect. If I change the size, the count remains the same more or less.
This is obviously not correct. Is the problem due to the RISCV compiler being used? We were using riscv64-unknown-elf. Do we need riscv64-unknown-linux-gnu?

Comment: What is your simulator of RISC-V? How can you get 900 cycles? Can you post the source code of test and assembler code?

Comment: Likely, you have some error in measuring the cycles.

Answer (score 1):

I'd made the similar performance test and compared the result with the SPARC-V8 LEON3 processor, so I've got the following data:

- Copying 8 KB (Kilo Bytes) block
- LEON3: 11780 clock cycles.
- Rocket: 14630 clock cycles.

I've used modificated single-core Rocket configuration with disabled L2 cache and with the own implementation of the NASTI arbiter to provide 1 clock access to the AXI devices. Most probably you will have worse result with the default config.

My SoC implementaiton: https://github.com/sergeykhbr/riscv_vhdl